# Riverpod StateNotifier lost state when parent provider refresh

Tags: flutter, state, riverpod

I have been trying to work out a solution for it but no luck. The key problem here is when you have a StateNotifier that depends on another provider, A fresh from the parent provider will cause the StateNotifier to be regenerated and result in existing state lost. I will use a simple example to explains my problem.
Here are the providers:

```
class Pair {
  final int parentValue;
  final int childValue;

  Pair({required this.parentValue, required this.childValue});

  Pair copyWith({int? parentValue, int? childValue}) {
    return Pair(
        parentValue: parentValue ?? this.parentValue,
        childValue: childValue ?? this.childValue
    );
  }
}

class PairNotifier extends StateNotifier<Pair> {
  // parentValue comes from counterProvider but childValue is maintained in existing notifier
  PairNotifier(int parentValue): super(Pair(parentValue: parentValue, childValue: 0));

  Pair increment() {
    final value = state.childValue + 1;
    state = state.copyWith(childValue: value);
    return state;
  }
}

final counterProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

final pairStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<PairNotifier, Pair>((ref) {
  //Image there are more watch in real world case.
  final parentValue = ref.watch(counterProvider); 
  // when counter is updated, PairNotifier is regenerated therefore childValue is lost.
  return PairNotifier(parentValue);
});
```

I would like to know if there is a way to preserve the existing state when all its' parent providers refreshed. Surely there should be a elegant solution since this library has been out there for quite some time.

Comment: I think you just need to make your providers independence, one to hold parentValue and other hold childValue.

Comment: I would sugget passing the provider's "ref" to the StateNotifier, so you can update the state of your counter and the pair in a method.  This is a common practice, here the [link](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#obtaining-a-ref-from-a-provider)

Comment: @Juan Carlos Ramón Condezo My only concern is for unit testing. If I want to test the business logic in the StateNotifier, how can I mock all those dependencies? Say if I have some repositories that I depend on.

Comment: @dante That means I will need to give up StateNotifier?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Ramón Condezo And can we use watch inside the StateNotifier? I'm just imaging when if there is a scenario that the notifier is depending on something(e.g. userRepo), and it needs to update the state base on the user changed but not losing some data of the existing state.

Comment: @PandaWorld why do you need to give up StateNotifier? Same as other comments, you can save Ref inside your State and use it to read other providers.

Comment: @dante appreciate your input. I would love to pass in ref too, but one scenario is blocking me that if the notifier's state is depending on something(e.g. userRepo), then it would need to update the state when user is changed. Can I watch the userRepo inside the StateNotifier. It would be great if you can provide a simple code sample.

Comment: Is this your use case? Provider A is depending on Provider B. It means when B change state, you need to change state of A too. Solution 1: when B change, use ref of B to read A then notify A that B is changed. Solution 2:  if 2 providers is depending on each other, why don't you combine them into 1 provider, this way will be much easier to use I think.

Comment: @PandaWorld I just remembered that Riverpod support ref.listen so A can listen on B changes and update arcodingly. More info please check the doc.

Comment: @dante that seems like a workable solution. Really appreciate your suggestion!

Comment: I'm having a discussion with Remi about this case https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/discussions/1259

Answer (score 2):

i also got these issue,
Actually there are 2 type of ref objects `WidgetRef` and `ProviderRef`.

- In simple `WidgetRef` used inside widget tree
- `ProviderRef` is used to communicate between providers

So in widget you will watch the providers and its values, but as in our case we try to watch providers inside another provider, actually we need to read the provider data inside another provider. If we watch provider data, it will change when another provider data is changed/ manipulated.

In short, use `ref.read() method`

```dart
final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter, int>((ref) {
  return Counter(ref);
});

class Counter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  Counter(this.ref): super(0);

  final Ref ref; //it is provided ref

  void increment() {
    // Counter can use the "ref" to read other providers

    final repository = ref.read(repositoryProvider);

    //in side provider we dont want to watch any changes 
    //we only need to read the data of other provider
    repository.post('...');
  }
}
```

for more you can go through [official doc](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading)